# Emacs and Prolog

Tags: emacs, prolog, swi-prolog

I downloaded SWI Prolog today but, I am having trouble getting emacs to recognize my prolog files. I am saving my prolog files with the extension `.pl` however, It keeps thinking they are perl files. In my home directory I have my `./.emacs file` and I have my `prolog.el` file. Also at the end of my `./.emacs` file I appended the following:

```
(autoload 'run-prolog "prolog" "Start a Prolog sub-process." t)
(autoload 'prolog-mode "prolog" "Major mode for editing Prolog programs." t)
(autoload 'mercury-mode "prolog" "Major mode for editing Mercury programs." t)
(setq prolog-system 'swi)
(setq auto-mode-alist (append '(("\\.pl$" . prolog-mode)
                                ("\\.m$" . mercury-mode))
                               auto-mode-alist)
```

I am using this sample `.emacs` file: [Sample Emacs File](http://www.dotemacs.de/dotfiles/sample.emacs.html)

Why will emacs not recognize my prolog file? I am not that experienced with emacs, so all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need your own prolog.el, since Emacs comes with one (and with the corresponding autoloads).  OTOH your change to auto-mode-alist looks correct and should fix your problem, so I'm not sure why it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Emacs comes pre-configured to work with Perl rather than Prolog for .pl, because Perl is much more commonplace. Add this to your .emacs to change the configuration permanently:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(pl\\|pro\\|lgt\\)" . prolog-mode))
```

If you just want to do it once for a single file and editing session, `M-x prolog-mode` will do it.